# How to make text with 'font-size: ~small' center in the table row

Tags: html, css

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/atom999/pen/eYpZXqK

```
<head>
<style>
span {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<table>
  <td>
  <td> Choose >>> </td>
    <td>
        <input name="vid" type="radio" id="foo" checked>
    <span>
      this text is too low, I want it centered with the radio button
    </span>  
  </td>
</table>
```

The app I'm working on has "font-size: 8pt;".. and I can't really change that.  But all I want to do is CENTER that smaller text in the  row, with a radio button.  I've tried all the 'font' and 'size' related styles and nothing seems to allow me to center that smaller text in the table row.

How can I do this?

Comment: simply make td a flex container, using display:flex; and then set, align-items:center; and your task is done. Please check my answer and rate if it helps :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic flex-property, **align-items:center**; the text gets aligned with your radio button:

```css
.tableRow{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>
span {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
</head>
  

<table>
  <td>
  <td> Choose >>> </td>
 <td class="tableRow">
  <input name="vid" type="radio" id="foo" checked>
    <span>
      this text is too low, I want it centered with the radio button
    </span>  
  </td>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your `.css` file:

```
input[name="vid"] {
span {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}  
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

@Atom999 I changed your `<span>` element into a flex container and made the elements inline to center with your radio button. Hope this helps!

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 8pt;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <td>
      <td> Choose >>> </td>
      <td>
        <input name="vid" type="radio" id="foo" checked>
        <span>
      this text is too low, I want it centered with the radio button
        </span>  
      </td>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex layout for the alignment.

```
<head>
<style>
span {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<table>
  <td>
  <td> Choose >>> </td>
    <td style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
        <input name="vid" type="radio" id="foo" checked>
    <span>
      this text is too low, I want it centered with the radio button
    </span>  
  </td>
</table>
```